# gsutil without -m multithreading / parallel default behavior

Tags: multithreading, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to find out if `gsutil mv` is called without the `-m` option, what the defaults are.  I see in the `config.py` source code that it looks like even without the `-m` option the default would be to calculate the number of CPU cores and set that along with 5 threads. So by default if you had a 4 core machine you would get 4 processes and 5 threads, basically multi-threaded out of the box.  How would we find out what `-m` does, I think I saw in some documentation that `-m` defaults to 10 threads, but how many processes are spawned?  I know you can override these settings but whats default with `-m`?

```
should_prohibit_multiprocessing, unused_os =ShouldProhibitMultiprocessing()
if should_prohibit_multiprocessing:
  DEFAULT_PARALLEL_PROCESS_COUNT = 1
  DEFAULT_PARALLEL_THREAD_COUNT = 24
else:
  DEFAULT_PARALLEL_PROCESS_COUNT = min(multiprocessing.cpu_count(), 32)
  DEFAULT_PARALLEL_THREAD_COUNT = 5
```

Also would a `mv` command in a `for` loop take advantage of `-m` or will it just feed the `gsutil` command one at a time rendering parallel obsolete? The reason I ask because using the below loop with 50000 files took 24 hours to complete, I wanted to know if I used the `-m` option if it would of helped? Not sure if calling the `gsutil` command each iteration would allow full threading or would it just do it with 10 processes and 10 threads making it twice as fast?

```
#!/bin/bash

for files in $(cat listing2.txt) ; do  
    echo "Renaming: $files --> ${files#removeprefix-}"
    gsutil mv gs://testbucket/$files gs://testbucket/${files#removeprefix-}
done
```

Comment: What is you file size? What do you want to achieve? in which duration? You want to upload thousand of files? Per day? Only once for migration?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I was attempting to rename in place, meaning do not bring the files out of GC. There are 50000 files at around 100MB each ~5TB total. This was a one time deal for us, but it could be needed again. I am trying to find out if -m would of helped or would it of been the same as gsutil default. Also what is the default amount of processes and threads when using -m. And last if using a for loop calling gsutil would take advantage of multi threads. Or would it just feed the files one at a time not using parallel operations.

Comment: -m param has a big impact for small files because protocol overhead is important compare to the file size. Here, the advantage of the -m will be quite invisible. Is your bandwidth could support more than 1Gbits/s ? Anyway, I never cope with this case. Here 2 links that I found: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas  and   https://medium.com/@duhroach/optimizing-google-cloud-storage-small-file-upload-performance-ad26530201dc

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes I think you are correct, my example of a for loop I just tested with -m and did not help.  It still iterates over each call and waits to start the next one.  I have sufficient bandwidth over 1GB but I think I would need to possibly have each request complete in the background to take advantage of -m.

Comment: Add a `&` at the end of `gsutil` in your script, if you want to spawn new thread. But like this, you will spawn 50000 thread in same time. You have to engineer a little your script for doing chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters @guillaume blaquiere, 
I engineered a python program that would multi process the API calls to move the files in the cloud with 25 concurrent processes.  I will share the code here to hopefully help others.

```
import time
import subprocess
import multiprocessing


class GsRenamer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gs_cmd = '~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil'

def execute_jobs(self, cmd):
    try:
        print('RUNNING PARALLEL RENAME: [{0}]'.format(cmd))
        print(cmd)
        subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print('[{0}] FATAL: Command failed with error [{1}]').format(cmd,
                                                                     e)

def get_filenames_from_gs(self):
    self.file_list = []
    cmd = [self.gs_cmd, 'ls',
           'gs://gs-bucket/jason_testing']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = p.stdout.readlines()
    for files in output:
        files = files.decode('utf-8').strip()
        tokens = files.split('/')[-1]
        self.file_list.append(tokens)
        self.file_list = list(filter(None, self.file_list))

def rename_files(self, string_original, string_replace):
    final_rename_list = []
    for files in self.file_list:
        renamed_files = files.replace(string_original,
                                      string_replace)
        rename_command = "{0} mv gs://gs-bucket/jason_testing/{1} " \
                         "gs://gs-bucket/jason_testing/{2}".format(
            self.gs_cmd, files, renamed_files)
        final_rename_list.append(rename_command)
        final_rename_list.sort()
    multiprocessing.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(
        processes=25)
    multiprocessing.pool.map(self.execute_jobs, final_rename_list)


def main():
    gsr = GsRenamer()
    gsr.get_filenames_from_gs()
    #gsr.rename_files('sample', 'jason')
    gsr.rename_files('jason', 'sample')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```